# Android - arrays of arrays

Tags: android, arrays

I am working with an onItemClick method on a ListActivity. I want to use putExtra to insert an array based on the position of the clicked item.

The categories array returns one null in the array. Obviously the @array/main does not work. Can anyone help? The code and XML is below.

```
String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories);
Intent i = new Intent(parent.getContext(), CategoriesActivity.class);
i.putExtra("categories", categories[position]);
startActivity(i);   

<array name="categories">
    <item>@array/main</item>
</array>

<string-array name="main">
<item>News</item>
<item>Sport</item>
<item>Business</item>
<item>Comment</item>
<item>Life</item>
<item>Society</item>
<item>Culture</item>
<item>Blogs</item>
 </string-array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be,

```
Resources res = getResources();
TypedArray ta = res.obtainTypedArray(R.array.categories);
```

Further you can iterate it using an [**answer of StackOverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5931094/726863) itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this would work.

```
String[] categories = getResources().getStringArray(R.string.main);
Intent i = new Intent(parent.getContext(), CategoriesActivity.class);
i.putExtra("categories", categories[position]);
startActivity(i);
```