# string-array inside string-array

Tags: android, xml, string, arrays

I want to create a string-array inside another string-array like this:

```
<string-array name="names">
        <string-array name="man">
            <item>Jake</item>
          </string-array>
            <string-array name="woman">
            <item>Loise</item>
          </string-array>
</string-array>
```

But I don't know how to access to de string-array inside the main string-array. Before doing it this way, I had organized all names in the same string-array and I accessed this way:

```
String names[] = res.getStringArray(R.array.names);
```

But now I need to classify the data. How can I access to the SUB string-arrays?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The outer array should be an array, not a string array (since it's not holding strings anymore). You want to declare the string arrays separately, and then an array with references to these string arrays as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326037/android-resource-array-of-arrays) (SO-thread, see accepted answer). Retrieval is also explained.