# How to get a value from a typed array resource by name in Android?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a resource xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="difficulties">
        <item>
            <integer name="level">1</integer>
            <integer name="fixed_blocks">2</integer>
            <integer name="color_count">2</integer>
        </item>
        <item>
            <integer name="level">2</integer>
            <integer name="fixed_blocks">4</integer>
            <integer name="color_count">3</integer>
        </item>
        <item>
            <integer name="level">3</integer>
            <integer name="fixed_blocks">6</integer>
            <integer name="color_count">3</integer>
        </item>
    </array>    
</resources>
```

How can I get the integer values from an `item` by name? The `TypedValue`'s API doesn't seem to contain any methods for this. If this is not possible with the `TypedArray` how IS it?

If I can get a value from an item by its ordinal it will be OK too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't recall this being possible(but I could be wrong). Judging by the structure of an item(in the `difficulties` array) you could do something else, you could use an array of integer arrays. Knowing that the item array has `level` at the first position, `fixed_blocks` as the second position etc you could easily get the values. An example of this you can find here [Android Resource - Array of Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326037/android-resource-array-of-arrays)

**Edit:**
Is this the method you're looking for?

```
private int[] getLevelConstants(int level) {
    int[] result = null;
    TypedArray ta = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.difficulties);
    // keep in mind the differences between the level(starts at 1) and the index of the difficulties array which starts at 0
    int id = ta.getResourceId(level, 0); 
    if (id > 0) {
        result = getResources().getIntArray(id);
    } else {
        // something bad
    }
    return result;
}
```

and the array will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <integer-array name="difficulties">
        <item>@array/level1</item>
        <item>@array/level2</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="level1" >
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </integer-array>

    <integer-array name="level2" >
        <item>2</item>
        <item>4</item>
        <item>3</item>
    </integer-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I receive an index from another activity which points to a specific difficulty (so I get 2 for example) and I need to get the element from the TypedArray by index and after that check out its elements.

Comment: @AdamArold By difficulty 2 you mean `level` 2 in the array item, right? If this is the case then the `level` integer has a simple mapping with the index of the `difficulties` array, you just have to subtract `1`(the `difficulties` array starts the index at 0 and the level starts from 1) from the index and there you have it.

Comment: No the problem is that I can't use R.array.difficulties.level1 for example since I can't hardcode that in my program, I only have an index. I can't use R.array.difficulties either since I can't extract my iteger-array from it with a method, I can only extract string-arrays. So I don't have the Resource id I need in order to look it up from Resources I just have an ordinal for an internal element of a resource.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of getResourceId()