# How to get the ID of selected item in a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I've a Spinner, with following values/properties.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:entries="@array/spin_ent"
    android:prompt="@string/spin_prompt" />

<string-array name="spin_ent">
    <item id="2">Two</item>
    <item id="1">One</item>
    <item id="3">Three</item>
    <item id="4">Four</item>
    <item id="5">Five</item>
</string-array>
```

From code level, I'm using the below code to get the `ID` of selected `item`.

```
final long spinID= ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin)).getSelectedItemId();
```

If I select Two, I'm getting `0` instead of `2`.

Why?

Comment: you should have implemented [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) interface and then get the selected item in [onItemSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html#onItemSelected) callback method

Comment: An option is to store it in an arrayList , so that you can get the item within that based on index

Comment: [Check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12675836/1398150).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement an `setOnItemSelectedListener`. Check the code below to help you understand better.

```
int count;
spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

spinner1 .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                spinner1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                count = position; //this would give you the id of the selected item
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ru sure item tag supports id attribute. I m finding problems here.  Its returning its row_id in the spinner.

```
<string-array name="spin_ent">
 <item id="2">Two</item>
 <item id="1">One</item>
 <item id="3">Three</item>
 <item id="4">Four</item>
 <item id="5">Five</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: But eclipse is not showing error if i specify id attribute for item.