# Change text format of radio button and get list of all countries and put it in spinner Android

Tags: android, radio-button, spinner

Hi below is the screen shot of an activity containing a list of details for user to fill in. As u can see the choose gender  radio buttons do not match with rest of the text in the activity. They are kind of bold text. I would like to make it similar to remaining text in activity how can I do it?

Also instead of having the user to type the state and country name I would like to provide the list of all countries in a spinner and depending on the country selected the state spinner should be populated with cities of the country selected. How can I do this?

[image]

Below is my xml code for the above Activity

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/topic"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/full_name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/fname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/email" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/age" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/age"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_male" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio_female" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/postal_address" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/state" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/state"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/country" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textCapWords" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/done" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"` for each or your radio button

Comment: Thanks man :) Now the radio button text size is same as the the rest of text in activity but its still a little bold how to make it in a normal text?

Comment: May be I shud jst change the text color to greyish :P

Comment: Also anything on my second question. Fetching the list of all countries and states of respective countries???

Comment: For the country spinner, you can follow http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html, and for the state spinner, I think the best way is to populate it in the onItemSelected callback from the first spinner. If you want everything to be defined in xml you can have a look into array of arrays in resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326037/android-resource-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 1):

Answer 1: If you want same size, you can try this in your XML for RadioButton:
 "android:textColor="#404040" "

Answer 2: Good Examples are here: 
http://androidexample.com/Spinner_Basics_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=82&aaid=105

Comment: Thanks for the help man :) The link u provided in ans 2 tells us how to create a spinner which I am aware of. My question is from wer do I fetch the data of all countries and how.

Answer (score 1):

**Q2**
You need to store countries and states in your `strings.xml` as `string-array` and get values from there and populate your `ArrayAdapter` accordingly. Here is how

1. Populate your `ArrayAdapter` from the countries array and populate
   your country `spinner`
2. Get the country from first `spinner`.
3. Get your states from the state `array` accordingly
4. Populate your state `spinner` in the `setOnItemSelectedListener` of
   the country `spinner`

**Example**

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryArray, statesArray;
countryArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.countries,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
countryArray            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

statesArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.states,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
statesArray.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryArray);
        specialitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
stateSpinner.setAdapter(stateArray);
        specialitySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
switch (parent.getId()) {
country= (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
case R.id.country_spinner:
switch (position) {
case 0:
statesArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.country1states,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                stateSpinner.setAdapter(statesArray);
break;
case 1:
statesArray = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                        R.array.country2states,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                stateSpinner.setAdapter(statesArray);
break;
}
```

**Q1**
use `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"`

**Please note**
I have written this code here, so expect errors. Please modify the code accordingly.