# Declaring arrays of dimens, colors, resource IDs, or other non-standard datatypes in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, typed-arrays

I find myself wishing to create xml arrays of values that Android doesn't seem to natively support, and am looking for some ways around the issue.

Currently, if you wish declare an Array of values in XML you're limited to Strings, ints, and a generic untyped "array", but what I'd really like is to be able to have arrays of reference IDs to colors, dimens, and the like.  Something like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="sizes">
        <item>@dimen/someSize1</item>
        <item>@dimen/someSize2</item>
        <item>@dimen/someSize3</item>
    </array>
    <array name="colors">
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/green</item>
        <item>@color/blue</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

Or as a stretch goal, being able to declare raw dimens / colors, and not just references.

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a good way to actually do this that I can find.  I can access the arrays

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
TypedArray array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyClass, defStyle, 0);

int sizesid = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyClass_sizes, defaultId);
int colorsid = array.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyClass_colors, defaultId);
```

This is all valid, and I get actual valid int arrays when I use these ids to retrieve the arrays like so

```
int[] colorIds = resources.getIntArray(colorsid);
```

The problem is that these integers *cannot* be used as valid reference IDs if I wish to resolve the actual color, or dimen.

```
resources.getColor(colorIds[0]); // Throws Resource NotFoundException
```

Is there any way to convert an int into a resource ID reference that's actually valid?  I assume this is why resources has separate getDimension / getInteger / getIdentifier.

---

*EDIT*: The goal here being to reference these arrays from custom xmlns params that I've defined in an appropriate attrs.xml so that they can be included in xml layout files, like so:

```
<com.example.MyClass
     xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     custom:sizes="@array/sizes"
     custom:colors="@array/colors" />
```

This is why my example uses context.obtainStyledAttributes to get a TypedArray object, and why I'm using R.styleable.foo resources to access its values.  I've found that arrays of Strings work just fine.  The problem is these arrays of reference IDs (or arrays of complex colors/dimens), and that they don't appear to contain meaningful values when I access them.

Comment: may be duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326037/android-resource-array-of-arrays/43462518#43462518

Comment: @Bill it's not.

Answer (score 4):

I'm 100% positive you can do exactly what you've already tried. I know this because I've used them before. More specifically, an array of string IDs. However, you're problem lies in when you're trying to retrieve them. Keep it as a `TypedArray`, and use `.getResourceId`, passing in the index and a default ID incase something goes wrong.

What I used is `getString(mTypedArray.getResourceId(position, 0))` in an Adapter. What're you're doing is passing an ID (wrong) when it's looking for an INDEX.

**EDIT**: And for further clarification, when I retrieve my TypedArray, I do it like this:

`getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.name_of_array)`

Comment: Hi!  I'm not ignoring you, I've just been incredibly busy with other work.  I'll get back to this question and your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: While I am passing an id in the form of R.styleable.MyClass_sizes, those ids *are* in fact array locations.  It might not be obvious, but what I have done is created custom xmlns attributes so that I can reference these arrays inside of custom xml attributes... but also, your example talks about getting Strings, which *does* work for me.  It's colors and dimens that I have an issue with.

Comment: I just saw your edit. I think I know what you're trying to achieve now. Are you trying to pretty much have the sizes and colors able to autocomplete in an XML for a custom view?

Comment: Not so much for autocomplete, but yes I would like to declare in XML that an instance of that View/Layout subclass should have references to arrays of complex values like colors and dimens, and ideally that these arrays contain references to colors / dimens so that the correct ones are selected from the appropriate res folders.

Comment: Can we see your `attrs.xml`? Specifically, does it have something like this: `<attr name="sizes" format="reference" />`. And, if it does, you might want to switch to going about this a different way. Instead of putting the array ID in the xml, use an enum and limit it to the choices you need ("big_size", "blue_colors", or however you're clarifying these two). Then, in your custom view, check for this and set them to the appropriate array, which you should be able to pull from your resources.

Comment: That's unfortunate.  The reason I'd like to do it the way i describe is that I want the View to be reusable, and hard coding references to res/array XML files into the Java class defeats this.