# reference string array res id from an array

Tags: android, xml

I have the following XML

```
<string-array name="str_arr1">
  <item>My item 1</item>
  <item>My item 2</item>
  <item>My item 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="str_arr2">
  <item>My item 4</item>
  <item>My item 5</item>
  <item>My item 6</item>
</string-array>
```

How can I reference the above strings arrays using an array.. something like  below (maybe another type of array needs to be used?)

```
<string-array name="my_strings_arrays">
  <item>R.array.str_arr1</item>
  <item>R.array.str_arr2</item>
</string-array>
```

Basically in the code, I want to read the `my_strings_arrays` and then for each array , I want to grab the list of items within.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second array should be an **array** of string arrays, not **string array** of string arrays.

I think the way you would do what you need is:

```
<array name="my_strings_arrays">
    <item>@array/str_arr1 </item>
    <item>@array/str_arr2 </item>
</array>
```

Comment: hmm interesting, can you update the answer with how you can load such thing using code? For example, how to display item1? Thank you so much

Comment: Actually, [here's a good example already](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5931094/3928341) instead of me typing it here.

Comment: @Snake no problem, glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

In any xml resource file we can use reference of array/string/integer/color/etc. with "`@`" prefix.
So, here we can use `@array` for getting reference of another array `str_arr1` and `str_arr2`.

```
<string-array name="str_arr1">
  <item>My item 1</item>
  <item>My item 2</item>
  <item>My item 3</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="str_arr2">
  <item>My item 4</item>
  <item>My item 5</item>
  <item>My item 6</item>
</string-array>
```

You to need change your code as below.

```
<string-array name="my_strings_arrays">
  <item>@array/str_arr1</item>
  <item>@array/str_arr2</item>
</string-array>
```